# run Spark-Submit on YARN but Imbalance (only 1 node is working)

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn

i try to run **Spark Apps** on **YARN-CLUSTER (2 Nodes)** but it seems those 2 nodes are imbalance because only 1 node is working but another one is not.

My Script :

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi 
--master yarn-cluster --deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 2 
--driver-memory 1G 
--executor-memory 1G 
--executor-cores 2 spark-examples-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar 1000
```

I see one of my node is working but another is not, so this is imbalance :

[image]
Note : in the left is `namenode`, and `datanode` is on the right...

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The complete dataset could be local to one of the nodes, hence it might be trying to honour data locality. 
You can try the following config while launching *spark-submit*

***--conf "spark.locality.wait.node=0"***

The same worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you are running job in `yarn-cluster` mode, in cluster mode Spark driver runs in the ApplicationMaster on a cluster host

try running it in `yarn-client` mode, in client mode Spark driver runs on the host where the job is submitted, so you will be able to see output on console

```
spark-submit --verbose --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--num-executors 2 \
--driver-memory 1G \
--executor-memory 1G \
--executor-cores 2 spark-examples-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar 10
```

Comment: but i want to run it on cluster mode

Comment: if you just want to see the output, you can see it in yarn logs using "yarn logs -applicationId <yarn application id>" . you can also modify SparkPi and store output on HDFS or some db.

Comment: How to find applicationId ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check on which node the executor are launched from SPARK UI

Spark UI gives the details of nodes where the execution are launched

Executor is the TAB in Spark UI

[image]